# How to initialize NumericVector to a specific size after it has been declared?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I wrote the following Rcpp code which compiles but does not give the expected result.

```
    // [[Rcpp::export]]
RObject test_1 (Rcpp::NumericVector& x)
{
  NumericVector x1;
  if (x.size() < 5)
  {
    NumericVector x1(x.size()*3);
    for (int ii = 0; ii < x.size(); ii++)
    {
      x1[ii] = sqrt(x[ii]);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    NumericVector x1(x.size()*2);
    for (int ii = 0; ii < x.size(); ii++)
    {
      x1[ii] = sqrt(x[ii]);
    }
  }
  return x1;
}
```

x1, the return vector is declared outside the if statement where the size of the returned vector x1 can vary. But if I declare the NumericVector with the size it created a new object, but the x1 that is returned in an empty vector.

The following code works:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
RObject test (const Rcpp::NumericVector& x)
{
  NumericVector x1;
  if (x.size() < 5)
  {
    NumericVector tmp(x.size()*3);
    for (int ii = 0; ii < x.size(); ii++)
    {
      tmp[ii] = sqrt(x[ii]);
    }
    x1 = tmp;
  }
  else
  {
    NumericVector tmp(x.size()*2);
    for (int ii = 0; ii < x.size(); ii++)
    {
      tmp[ii] = sqrt(x[ii]);
    }
    x1 = tmp;
  }
  return x1;
}
```

Here I declare temp numericvector and then set x1 to that vector.

I did this a while ago and know that there is a way to set a NumericVector to a specific size after it has been declared, I just cannot remember how.

Edit: Edited the code and question to show how the return vector size is not known before the if statement.

Comment: "*(I know this is not the case in the example)*" - Please clarify your question with a representative example of your situation.

Comment: I do not know `r`, but I am looking at this in terms of C++.  If this code compiled, then RObject should have a constructor that takes a NumericVector so that the return value is copied correctly, and a new `RObject` created.   In other words, the code should not have crashed since I don't see any pointer manipulation going on in the client (your) code.

Comment: @Alvin I'm a little confused at your objective - regardless of the size of `x`, only the first `x.size()` elements of `x1` are going to be given values (`sqrt(x[ii])`). In the case of `x.size() < 5`, the `[x.size(), 3*x.size()-1]` range of values in `x1` will be default initialized to `0`, and in the case of `x.size() >= 5`, the `[x.size(), 2*x.size()-1]` range of values in `x1` will be default initialized to `0`. Is that correct?

Comment: The objective is to set x1 to a certain size inside the if statement. Everything else is secondary. I can fill x1 with any values I like, but that is not important, I just want to set x1 to certain size without having to create a tmp vector and set x1 equal to that. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use this style:

```
NumericVector x;
if (foo)
    x = NumericVector(1);
else
    x = NumericVector(2);
```

Or even (if you want to avoid zero initialization of the generated vector)

```
x = static_cast<NumericVector>(no_init(size));
```

Note that when you write

```
NumericVector x;
if (foo)
    NumericVector x(1);
```

you are actually creating *two* `NumericVector` objects called `x` -- one living at the top-level scope, and one living within the scope of the `if` statement.

That is, it's worth understanding that when you write

```
NumericVector x;
```

you are actually *creating* an object, not just declaring an object (that is only true for built-in types, e.g. `int`). So, when you write `NumericVector x`, `x` is actually default-constructed with the zero-argument `NumericVector` constructor (which creates a numeric vector of length 0)

Answer (score 2):

You could conditionally `resize` a `std::vector<double>` and `Rcpp::wrap()` it, like this:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::RObject test_1(const Rcpp::NumericVector& x) {

  std::vector<double> x1;
  if (x.size() < 5) {
    x1.resize(3*x.size());
  } else {
    x1.resize(2*x.size());
  }
  for (int ii = 0; ii < x.size(); ii++) {
    x1[ii] = sqrt(x[ii]);
  }
  return Rcpp::wrap(x1);
}

/*** R

xa <- 1:3
xb <- 1:10

test_1(xa)
# [1] 1.000000 1.414214 1.732051 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000

test_1(xb)
#[1] 1.000000 1.414214 1.732051 2.000000 2.236068 2.449490 2.645751 2.828427 3.000000 3.162278 0.000000 0.000000
[13] 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000

length(test_1(xa))/length(xa)
#[1] 3
length(test_1(xb))/length(xb) 
#[1] 2

*/
```

Comment: Thank you, but the question is about when you do not know the size that x1  should be before the for loop. I will modify the original question to make it more clear.

Comment: Thanks nrussell, this works too. Just wondering if x1 is already a large vector, does .resize() copy each element or does it just add a new vector to the end efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this

```
RObject test_1 (Rcpp::NumericVector x)
{
    for (int ii = 0; ii < x.size(); ii++)
    {
       x[ii] = sqrt(x[ii]);
    }
    return x;
}
```

By passing by value you create a new `NumericVector` of the same size of the original one

if you don't want to change your API, the second code is OK but the temp var is not necessary

```
 RObject test_1 (const Rcpp::NumericVector& x)
{
    NumericVector x1(x.size());
    for (int ii = 0; ii < x.size(); ii++)
    {
       x1[ii] = sqrt(x[ii]);
    }
    return x1;
}
```

Comment: It seems you are changing the original values of x and returning the value. While this works, I am trying to learn how to work with a vector of unknown size in a different scope. Which is why I declare x1 outside the for loop or if statement, but allocate the proper size inside the loop.

Comment: if you pass by value you won't change the value of the function argument

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel `The types really are pointer types`  Which is why I hate having pointers typedefed away or hidden under the covers.  The code looks like it is manipulating objects.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  That is all good and true in the abstract sense but unavoidable here. We are operating in the confines of an API we are given -- see the R language definitions on `SEXP` types.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Well, if they are pointer types, then the code produces undefined behavior as it is returning a pointer to a local variable.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  Let's take this off-line.  You are looking at an Rcpp answer; there are a few hundred other Qs and As here for it; please take a look around and/or look at the other Rcpp documentation -- as well as the R documentation providing the interface handed to Rcpp.

Comment: To be precise, `NumericVector`s are proxy objects -- they just contain a pointer to some data under the hood; they aren't really pointer types themselves. So copying a `NumericVector` amounts to copying an object which contains a pointer to some data (whose lifetime is managed through RAII + R's own memory management system)